# what's the taylor serie and it's convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I have this problem:

> What is the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x}$ at $x_0 = 4$. What is its
>   interval of convergence?

I am stuck and I can not finish it.

Any idea on how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Aretino nothing important, just small tests that do not conclude to a final result.

Comment: If you know the answer for $\sqrt{1+t}$ at $0$, write $x=x_0+h=4+h$, and deal with $\sqrt{4+h} = 2\sqrt{1+h/4}$ instead.